# How to make an object of a class that extends Dictionary

Tags: c#

A class inherits class Dictionary. How can I make an object of that class.

```
Class A : Dictionary <string , object>
{
   A();
}

Dictionary<string , object> d=new Dictionary<string , object>();

A a= new A(d);
```

The above code is not working.

```
Dictionary<string, object> p = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"PKeyId","81614-901-000001-124"}
        };
        ODataActionParameters parameter = (ODataActionParameters) new Dictionary<string, object>(p);
```

The above code is causing issue.

Comment: Why do you suspect it should be working? It does not work that way. Just call `A a = new A();`. You seem to be mixing up `has-a` and `is-a` design. Pick one and go with it.

Comment: Basically I am trying to make an object of OdataActionParameters. If I use your way to create object then it gives null exception when i run my program

Comment: If you need debugging help, please post a [mcve].

Comment: "not working", "causing issue", neither of those are problem *descriptions*, please post *the actual result* as well as what you expected.

Comment: *"The above code is not working."* *"The above code is causing issue."* Very descriptive ...

Answer (score 2):

You can call the base class constructor as follows

```
public class A : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    public A(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary) : base(dictionary)
    { }
}

Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();

A a = new A(d);
```